# Offline NodeJS Based Site

Tags: node.js

I am trying to create a digital vehicle gauge cluster. I am using a RasPi to gather speed, RPM, and engine temperature and am currently using NodeJS to pull sensor data from the GPIO pins.

My initial plan was to take advantage of my preexisting HTML/CSS skills to then display this data to the driver and update that local HTML site using `getElementById()` tags in my JS and write over the data values. However, when I launched my site I realized that Node wasn't being used since I hadn't actually asked Node to start interpreting anything.

Given that I already have this website GUI built and the JS done to write to it, is there a way for me to actually connect these two scripts? Is there a way for me to use Node to launch the website and initialize Node at the same time?

Hope this isn't a duplicate question or covered in documentation somewhere.

Thanks in advance for any tips.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking; there seems to be multiple questions. Are you asking how to start up the back-end app and run Chrome (in kiosk mode) on startup/reboot?

Comment: Sorry, I guess this did get a little convoluted. The root issue is that I need to be able to use Node modules on a local site. When I run the site now, I get a console error saying module not found.

Comment: Is the GUI running on the Pi or another server? Node can certainly serve views but it sounds like you have a site already built?

Comment: "Run node modules on a local site" doesn't have much meaning. There are client-side apps, and server-side apps. A client-side app, e.g., one in the browser, may or may not be able to use a specific Node module. A server-side app is a Node application. What is your GUI? A web app? An Electron app?

Comment: Yes, I'm just using Chromium on the RasPi to run an index.html. Do I need to also host that local site for Node to init?

Comment: @DaveNewton Sorry, it's just an index.html with an accompanying CSS stylesheet. Does that answer your question? I can upload to GitHub and share a link if you think that would help.

Comment: Sorry, I think my issue is that I need to just host the site locally. I'll try that and if that doesn't solve it I'll come back. Sorry to waste y'all's time.

Comment: Ok I think the issue I was having was that the modules I was trying to use were not compatible with Browserify. Current plan is to run a 'parent.js' file to launch the local site and run some of the modules that Browserify can't like GPIO, etc. Looking into web workers to translate data in between... we'll see how that goes.

Comment: One typical way to handle this is to have a server-side app that does all the hardware stuff, and a client-side app that can talk to it via normal HTTP or web sockets. An Electron app wraps all that up into a single application, but with a potentially annoying layer of complexity (and I haven't messed w/ Electron as a kiosk app--I assume it's possible, but *shrug*). Alternatively, throw away all the web-dev stuff and use any of several GUI toolkits and just write a simple app--but a web app w/ sockets is easy enough, and you have the benefit of a lot of existing work.

Comment: HAHA YES! Coming up with the same solution as one of the big kids on stack exchange is definitely going to pump my ego up today. I did some digging and decided a Node server-side app that interacts with the main script behind the site was the best path. Plus then I can avoid using workers. Thanks again for your help and guidance.